# div Layout breaks When Price is not set

Tags: css

The layout of the products breaks once I don't add a price as you can see in the link. http://wptemp.wendybellissimo.com/?pcategory=accessories

It does not respond with any class that I target? What class should I target?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You will need to hold the place of the price tag without displaying a price; `visibility: hidden` is perfect for this. Add a class like `no_price` if a price is not available and set the visibility to be hidden, like below.

```
<p class="sale_price no_price"></p>

p.no_price {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set a height of 45px  (or min-height) for the "sale_price" element. It seems like a bad habit to rely on content to keep your layout from breaking.

Comment: Thanks Scott, that works great. I was looking for clear: both; rule to separate the elements.